Why Git can't merge on the server-side if there are no conflicts
I've been using Git for a long time in a lite mode: branch, pull-commit-push, merge. Mostly with SourceTree. That was enough for development. So I'm an amateur)
But now I've got a repository that is watched by ArgoCD and which obtains pushes from different Gitlab pipelines. 99.9% of pushes go to their own folders. To tell you the truth I've never noticed a conflict. But as the number of pipelines grows we get more often:

error: failed to push some refs to '...'
Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. > Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

So the question is: why Git does not even try to merge the changes to remote branch throwing such error only if there are true conflicts? Because all you have to do is to pull changes and they never need any resolving and then repeat the push.
Git is almost 20 years old and is considered the most advanced VCS so I was surprised with such behaviour. Or maybe I've been searching not thoroughly enough and something is out there except brutal --force to deal with such situations?

Merging is a local operation. You want to know what you are pushing before you are pushing (the result of the merge could be different from what you expected). And if the merge was happening remotely, you'd have to fetch again before being able to continue working.

It's not a matter of conflicts. It's that in order to perform a true merge, you need a working tree so that Git can enact the merge. But the repo on the server is a bare repo; it has no working tree. Therefore only a fast-forward is possible. If you really want to perform merges on the server side, that is what pull requests / merge requests are for — but they are not a Git feature, they are a feature of GitHub, Bitbucket, and (yes) GitLab.

I can think of reasons.

Git servers are designed to be "dumb".
You could break the build.
Git is not an archive tool.

Dumb servers
By keeping the basic Git push/pull protocol simple, there's no need for a dedicated Git server. Git can use many different protocols including local files, or just an HTTP server with minimal changes. See The Protocols chapter of Pro Git for more.
Simplicity (not of the commands, but of the fundamentals) is one of Git's core strengths.
You can break the build and not know it
Allowing git push to merge for you would encourage sharing untested and broken code.
It's important to ensure the main branch works. That way, everyone is working from a stable base. If broken code is merged into main and shared, now potentially everyone else on the project is working with broken code.
A merge results in a new commit and code changes. If the merge is done by a git push on the server, you don't know what you just shared. There was no conflict, but does it work? Who knows? You might have just broken the main branch for everybody.
All work should be tested before sharing to avoid sharing broken work. This is why work is done in branches so they can be safely pushed and tested on CI before being merged. Ideally you merge main into your branch, test it, and then merge back into main.
Git is not a tool for <insert task here>

But now I've got a repository that is watched by ArgoCD and which obtains pushes from different Gitlab pipelines. 99.9% of pushes go to their own folders

You're using Git as an archive tool. It's not designed for that.
Git is a version control system. It is not a build system, a release manager, a dependency manager, a backup system, nor an archival system. But people try to use it for that anyway. Git will "work" to a point, but not well. Use a dedicated tool instead.

You are absolutely right about testing feature-branches and merging after pipilene succeeds. That's fair if we talk about regular development. But if you are familiar with the GitOps pattern than you probably know that Git is exactly that dedicated tool to store and version control k8s-manifests. And we don't need to test it, just push to different directories without errors until we face a true conflict in case of changing same files.

@donRumatta 1) GitOps uses pull requests for the reasons in this answer. 2) It would greatly complicate Git's networking protocol. 3) You can fetch and merge (or rebase) locally and then push the result. Much safer.

@donRumatta "99.9% of pushes go to their own folders" is a hint that there something special about your particular process. Perhaps ask a question with more detail about your particular process and how to avoid merge conflicts.

MRs are actual when helm-charts and other k8s stuff are prepared manually by devopses. But we are not true devopses but developers so everything is generated and pushed inside pipeline jobs without human participation. And I've already implemented pull-push with retries but it looks like a ceremony, not a useful action. Maybe you are right about XY because now I'm thinking about rewriting everything to a console app requesting Gitlab API to get rid of this elven git-bash)

Cui bono?
Traditionally and most commonly a merge requires a working tree. Which
means that you need to check out all files on disk.  There seems to be
support for merging without having to check out a working tree via
git-merge-tree(1) but that only landed in 2022 (proposal).
(According to a little research just now.)
Now such “server side merges” (quotes taken from the proposal) can be
useful for Git forges: people like Scott Channon have
said that it would be a good idea for Git forges to do speculative
“in-memory merges” (doesn’t use a working tree) between pull requests so
that people can get alerted when they might be heading into merge
conflicts relative to other pending pull requests.
But note the in-memory merge requirement. Apparently it is not feasible
for the Git forge servers to do such merges on-disk.
Which brings us to regular merges on push. What motivation is there for
people who host Git repositories on servers to provide server-side
merging? Up until recently they would have to check out all files (the
working tree) on disk. Apparently (again) that is too costly. Because
imagine if it was supported. Then it would happen all the time.
Because people just push things up and hope that it lands. Why check if
something is pushable if the server can try to do the merge for
me? [1]
Meanwhile the user has all the tools to do it themselves. Let them wear
out their own disks.
Notes

There are all the excellent reasons that Schwern mentioned. But
we assume that this user has not thought about or care about those
points.


Thank you for new interesting information) I was not waiting for Git trying to merge on every push and especially not hoping there will be any magic of conflicts resolving. But at the beginning of research I thought --force or some other flag will be able to say Git to try to merge when we are 100% sure there are will be no conflicts. And throw that error only on fail.

@donRumatta And the same thing applies in that case: historically (apparently) they would have to check out the working tree on disk to do a merge.
